# How to make a randomly generated 3D map using Java and Libgdx?

Tags: java, android, 3d, libgdx

Is there a way make a random generated 3D dungeon so it's different each time, I was wondering how would it work, would I have to set certain variables for example to make sure it works and isn't a loads of random colours like pink, green, blue and whatever else?

Also how would would I set it to say for example to be a medieval dungeon so like stone walls and so on? I'm guessing that I have to set a few variables for it to work on and then it makes a map/dungeon based on that?

Answer (score 0):

In short yes you can. You will need to research different algorithms to achieve your results as LibGDX (and pretty much anything else other than gamemaker) doesn't have any built in generation.

http://pcg.wikidot.com/pcg-algorithm:dungeon-generation

This is the website I used to learn random dungeon generation at first. Cellular Automata (cave generation) seems to be the easiest I recommend starting with that.